# unexpected behaviour of nested contenteditable DIVs in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, contenteditable

I have a WYSIWYG editor and I'm having problems with Firefox getting contenteditable to behave as expected.  The problem arises with nested DIVs when contenteditable is set on each.. for example:

https://jsfiddle.net/feqnj2gL/

```
<div contenteditable='true'>
    <div contenteditable='false' style='padding:20px;'>don't want this deleted
        <div contenteditable='true'>this is editable</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Clicking on the 'this is editable' text doesn't set the cursor as expected but instead selects all the text and the parent DIV too.

However - taking out contenteditable on the outermost DIV fixes the problem. Unfortunately in my application I need those 3 levels as the outermost layer is the BODY tag of an editable IFrame.

This code works in IE(!) and Chrome.  Is it a FF bug or am I missing something?

Comment: It's definitely a bug and I think that a pretty new one. I can also reproduce it with http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/captionedimage.html and I've never seen such behaviour before. If you report it, please post here a URL to the ticket.

Comment: OK, it turns out it's a serious bug in the latest Firefox release. We've just got a bug report about it – http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/13507. Few days ago it was OK. We'll report it to Mozilla.

Comment: I reported this bug to Mozilla https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1181130

Comment: Great - thanks for confirming!